# Tmux: How to copy text between nested remote ssh session and local machine

Tags: macos, ssh, tmux

I have tmux session locally that connects to multiple remote tmux sessions.

I am unable to figure how to copy text from these remote tmux sessions and the local machine.

Mysteriously, opening a remote ssh session (not nested in a local tmux) works.

Basically, If I start an ssh session and attach to the remote tmux then all works fine (copy/paste). On the other hand, if I start a local tmux then ssh to a remote system and attach to it's tmux session then I can't copy from that remote session to the local machine (I am on Catalina/MacOS). This seems very weird to me.

Answer (score 13):

I assume you mean copying text with copy mode in tmux?

tmux can set the host clipboard using the OSC 52 escape sequence, but it needs to be aware the outside terminal supports this and the outside terminal needs to be configured to allow it.

With only one tmux, you probably have `TERM=xterm` outside tmux and a terminal that allows this by default, so it will work without any configuration changes.

However, with two tmux, the inner tmux will have `TERM=screen` or `TERM=tmux` and an outside terminal (the outer tmux) that does not allow this by default.

So to make it work you need to do two things:

1) Configure the outer tmux to allow the clipboard to be set by programs inside with `set -g set-clipboard on` (don't forget to restart tmux entirely after changing .tmux.conf, or do this also from the command prompt).

2) Configure the inner tmux to set the clipboard when the outside terminal is also tmux by adding an `Ms` entry to terminal-overrides (change `screen*` to `tmux*` if you have `TERM=tmux` inside tmux): `set -as terminal-overrides ',screen*:Ms=\\E]52;%p1%s;%p2%s\\007'`. You will need to detach and reattach tmux after doing this if you don't restart it.

If the inner tmux is very old you may also need to do `set -g set-clipboard on` for it as well.

Comment: I am really interested in this solution , although I didn't quite understood what you mean by an `Ms` entry. Do you mean doing a line in `~/.tmux.conf` in the client-side ? with that `set -as terminal-overrides ',screen*:Ms=\\E]52;%p1%s;%p2%s\\007'` it is not working for me

Comment: This worked for me, thanks!
Only issue is that it seems to fail when I want to copy large amounts of text. (More than 150 lines.) Is there some limit? And if so, how do I expand it?

Comment: I used the instructions at https://github.com/tmux/tmux/wiki/Clipboard#quick-summary and it worked for me.

Comment: That works, you saved me from so much pain!